# Using Termux For wireless sniffing

Tags: root-access, 7.0-nougat

I have Termux on my unrooted Huawei GR5 mini running Nougat. It does not do that much in a unrooted device. If I root my device can I use net-tools on my Android. Does it also support airmon-ng for packet capture?

If not can I do so?

Comment: Re-compile the package from scratch by yourself.

Comment: Sound like a lot of work.